# Django query (contains, startswith, etc..) always case-insensitive

Tags: python, django, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Whenever I use Django's query functions like `name__contains` or `name__startswith` it is always case-insensitive, as if they were `name__icontains` or `name__istartswith`.

How could I force case-sensitivity?

I'm using Django `4.1.1` and Python `3.10`

```
def index_filter(request, name_filter):
    case_sensitive_results = Person.objects.filter(name__contains=name_filter).count()
    case_insensitive_results = Person.objects.filter(name__icontains=name_filter).count()
    context = {'case_sensitive_results': case_sensitive_results, 'case_insensitive_results': case_insensitive_results}
    return render(request, 'index2.html', context)
```

Comment: Please have a look at Django documentation, `contains` always case-sensetive and `icontains` always case-insensitive also startswith and istartwaith follows that. [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#std-fieldlookup-contains)

Comment: I have had a look! Everywhere on the Internet it says that contains is case-sensitive, but mine is not!

Comment: Without code example, we can not help you to find the problem. It is sure : contains is case-sensitive, your problem is elsewhere

Comment: What database are you using? What collation are you using for the fields? The documentation also has this note "_SQLite doesn’t support case-sensitive LIKE statements; contains acts like icontains for SQLite._"

Comment: Please share the output screen capture